# null pointer exception error calling method

Tags: java, methods, nullpointerexception

I get this null pointer exception error if i call a method.
if (farm1.cropStat(row, col) )

here's the method

```
public boolean cropStat(int row, int col)
{
    if( !( field1[row][col].harvested ) && field1[row][col] != null  )       
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

here's the initialization

```
public void initializeCrops()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int rRow=-1, cCol=-1;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i< 74; i++)
    {   
        while(rRow <0 || cCol <0)
        {
            rRow = rnd.nextInt() % 104;
            cCol = rnd.nextInt() % 104;
        }
        field1[rRow][cCol] = new Crops(rRow, cCol);
    }  
 }
```

pls help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see a pattern that looks like this

```
if (someCondition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

replace it with the equivalent

```
return someCondition.
```

It is the same thing.

As far as the error goes, you need to reverse the order of your checks in order to see that the item is not `null` before referencing it:

```
return field1[row][col] != null && !( field1[row][col].harvested );
```

Operator `&&` is designed in such a way that once it sees that the result is going to be false, it stops further evaluation. In the example above, `&&` will stop if `field1[row][col]` is `null`, preventing null pointer exception.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but I still get the null pointer exception problem. @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @JedrekFadul A more conservative check would go like this: `field1!=null && field1[row] != null && field1[row][col] != null && !( field1[row][col].harvested )`. Usually, though, this indicates that the setup hasn't set the array up in a way to make all cells of 2D array available.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize `field1` anywhere, so it is null when you try to assign values into it.

Comment: I did: @shimonb89                                                                                                 public Farm()
    { 
       field1 = new Crops[104][104];
    }

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of the expressions in the if statement:

```
if( field1[row][col] != null && !( field1[row][col].harvested ))
```